# How do I add a timestamp to the gem5 ruby cache?

Tags: caching, architecture, gem5

I am currently trying to implement a cache coherence protocol where I need to store current global timestamp for each cache block.

Do I need to update the timestamp variable in `CacheMemory.hh` or in `AbstractEntry.hh` or somewhere else?

Where can i find a detailed description of how the cache requests work?